# QuerySelectField Not Displaying Expected Output

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid, wtforms

I get the Error As `TypeError: 'Query' object is not callable`.

I am Creating a Blog Engine in Pyramid and i am stuck in QuerySelectField, how to display the categories present in separate Table called Categories which is a ForeignKey to the Articles Model ?

**Expected Output**

> *Category Field Should Show all the Category present in Database to choose from.*

**Models.py**

```
DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))
Base = declarative_base()

class Category(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'categories'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
    description = Column(Text, nullable=False)


class Article(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'articles'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    body =  Column(Text, nullable=False)
    category = Column(ForeignKey(Category.name), nullable=False)
    created = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now)

    @property
    def slug(self):
        return urlify(self.title)

    @property
    def created_in_words(self):
        return time_ago_in_words(Article.created)
```

**Views.py**

```
from pyramid.view import view_config
from pyramid.httpexceptions import HTTPFound
import sqlalchemy as sa
from blog.forms import ArticleCreateForm

from blog.models import (
    DBSession,
    Article, Category,
    )

@view_config(route_name='home', renderer='articles/index.jinja2')
def index(request):
    articles = DBSession.query(Article).order_by(sa.desc(Article.created))
    return {'articles': articles}

@view_config(route_name='article_action', match_param='action=create', renderer='articles/create.jinja2')
def create(request):
    article = Article()
    form = ArticleCreateForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        form.populate_obj(article)
        DBSession.add(article)
        return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('home'))
    return {'form':form, 'action':request.matchdict.get('create')}
```

**forms.py**

```
from models import DBSession
from models import Category
from wtforms import Form, TextField, TextAreaField, SubmitField, validators
from wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.fields import QuerySelectField

def Category_choice():
    return DBSession.query(Category.name)

class ArticleCreateForm(Form):
    title = TextField('Title', [validators.required(), validators.length(min=1,max=240)])
    body = TextAreaField('Content', [validators.required()])
    category = QuerySelectField('Category', query_factory=Category_choice())
    submit = SubmitField()
```

Comment: When asking a question related to the error, please include the full stack trace. Currently, we have to guess where your error is happening.

Comment: what @MarkHildreth said. also, the clue is in the param name I bet. it should be query_factory=Category_choice as in no "()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line from `query_factory=Category_choice()` to `query_factory=Category_choice` and

Change your **Category_choice** function as

```
def Category_choice():
    return DBSession.query(Category)
```

So your Forms look like this now

```
def Category_choice():
    return DBSession.query(Category)

class ArticleCreateForm(Form):
    title = TextField('Title', [validators.required(), validators.length(min=1,max=240)])
    body = TextAreaField('Content', [validators.required()])
    category = QuerySelectField('Category', query_factory=Category_choice )
    submit = SubmitField()
```

And in your Category Model add this method call

```
   def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Please Refer to [This Documentation](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6.1/ext.html#module-wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy) For detailed Explanation.

Hope It Helps.